# URLs showing in anchor tag text

Tags: html, url, anchor, phpbb3

Got a real head-scratcher, I have a forum using PHPBB3 in my site, it works fine on most browsers but am having some issues with IE and Firefox on PC revealing the HREF attribute directly in the  tag text on some links.

See the screenshot below:

[image: IE9 Screenshot]

However, in the HTML for this, there is absolutely no HREF in the anchor text.  Here is the HTML copied from the IE8 view source:

```
<p class="author">
  <a href="./viewtopic.php?p=2#p2">
    <img src="./styles/proSpecial/imageset/icon_post_target.gif" width="11" height="9" alt="Post" title="Post"  style="height:9px;;width:11px;" />
  </a>
  by
  <strong>
    <a href="./memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&amp;u=2" style="color: #AA0000;" class="username-coloured">
      admin
    </a>
  </strong> 
  &raquo; Tue Mar 12, 2013 5:00 pm 
</p>
```

You can see the page in question [here](http://www.retrogamesparty.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2)

Here are my findings:

Mac: All browser variants work just fine
PC: Chrome and Safari are fine, IE shows the links like in the picture, Firefox shows more revealed URLs.

Totally stuck for what to try, nothing in the CSS is trying to hide or reveal things so it seems like a browser quirk.

Note that on the left hand side, in all browsers, the author link doesn't reveal its URL, only in the right hand panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a strange entry in your CSS using the `:after` pseudo-class:

```
P A[href]:after {
    content: "" attr(title) "";
}
```

Somewhere in "style-fixer.php".

Comment: This was tricky, basically phpBB is using wp-united to bring both my wordpress front end theme and BB's together, the style-fixer.php loads my theme's css which, as mine was a child theme, was importing the main one but by this time, the media attribute wasn't being passed so the @media print {...} which is where the P A[href] is situated is not getting skipped.  One to fix later, i've overridden the element in my local one.